# Interceptor doesn't work on JMSAopBundle (Symfony2 AOP)

Tags: php, symfony, aop

I'm trying to make an aspect on Symfony2, but I followed the instructions in http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSAopBundle and I can't find what is the problem. This is my services.yml:

```
exception_pointcut:
        class:    AGF\Services\Aspects\Exceptions\ExceptionPointcut
        tags:
          - { name: jms_aop.pointcut, interceptor: exception_interceptor }  

exception_interceptor:
        class:    AGF\Services\Aspects\Exceptions\ExceptionInterceptor
        arguments: [@security.context, @logger]
```

This is my "pointcut":

```
<?php
namespace AGF\Services\Aspects\Exceptions;

use JMS\AopBundle\Aop\PointcutInterface;

class ExceptionPointcut implements PointcutInterface
    {

    public function matchesClass(\ReflectionClass $class) 
        {
        return true;
        }

    public function matchesMethod(\ReflectionMethod $method)
        {

            if($method->name == '__construct')
                {
                return false;   
                }

        }

    }
```

This is my Interceptor:

```
<?php
namespace AGF\Services\Aspects\Exceptions;

use CG\Proxy\MethodInterceptorInterface;
use CG\Proxy\MethodInvocation;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;

class ExceptionInterceptor implements MethodInterceptorInterface
    {

    private $context;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $context, LoggerInterface $logger)
        {

        $this->context = $context;
        $this->logger = $logger;    
        $this->logger->debug('HOLA2');

        }

    public function intercept(MethodInvocation $invocation) 
        {

        try {
            return $invocation->proceed();
            }   
        catch (\Exception $e)
            {
            $this->logger->err($e);
            }   

        }

    }
```

All classes reach the pointcut, but do not reach the interceptor. When I make an "echo" in the  pointcut (echo $method->name) the pointcut works, but when I make a debug in the interceptor nothing appears in the log.

Comment: You could try to first add a `return true;` at the end of `ExceptionPointcut::matchesMethod`

Comment: When I put "return true;" in ExceptionPointcut::matchesMethod I have this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function loadInterceptors() on a non-object in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/ebusagf/app/cache/dev/jms_aop/proxies/Symfony-Bridge-Monolog-Logger.php on line 37

Comment: I have the same problem, did you correct it?

Comment: the fatal error when always returning `true` from `matchesMethod` is explained  [here](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSAopBundle/issues/9#issuecomment-6893052). The problem is that you're trying to intercept *every* method, even constructors - when the proxy object doesnt yet have the interception loader